# MATLAB fminsearch for function minimization with 4 parameters

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I need to minimize this function:

```
A = sum(1:N) [(wi/constant)* y];
```

where

```
y = P - P0 + 10*n*log( sqrt((xk-xi)^2 + (yk-yi)^2) )
```

I know `P` at different locations (i.e for different `(xi,yi)`).  I have to find the parameters `P0`, `n`, `xk`, and `yk` which minimize `A`.

I want to use `fminsearch` in MATLAB to solve this problem, however, I did not know exactly how to use it?

I tried the idea on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240042/matlab-fminsearch-equation-using-four-anonymous-parameters?rq=1), however I need to use `Bm` as vector `(x,y)` and they use `Bm` as scalar?

Could I use `fminsearch` to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `wi`? And I assume you mean that the function is the sum of all elements? I also assume the function `A` takes as an input vectors `xi` and `yi`?

Comment: (wi/constant) is a weight for the signal y. also N is the number of the collected data.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your function seems to be unbounded (result: `-inf`),  because

- `P0` is unconstrained and can therefore grow to `+∞`, leading to `A ⇒ -∞`
- `n` is unconstrained and can therefore shrink to `-∞`, leading to `A ⇒ -∞`
- `xk` and `yk` can be chosen such that the sum of all squares is minimal, therefore, you are taking the log of a tiny number, which tends to `-∞`, leading to `A ⇒ -∞`

So, you'd probably have to use some constraints or scaling; if you have the optimization toolbox, it's `fmincon` you're looking for.

If you don't have the toolbox: there's [`fminsearchbnd` and `fminsearchcon`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon), available from the file exchange, or my very own [`optimize`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24298-optimize).

Anyway, here's how you'd implement your problem using `fminsearch`:

```
%// Some dummy values (for testing)
N = 30;

w = rand(N,1);   x = rand(N,1);
P = rand(N,1);   y = rand(N,1);

constant = rand;

%// Define Q = [P0 n xk yk]. Then: 
A = @(Q) sum( w.*(P - Q(1) + 10*Q(2)*log(sqrt((Q(3)-x).^2 + (Q(4)-y).^2))) )/constant;

%// Most local optimization algorithms need an initial estimate: 
Q0 = rand(4,1);

%// Now you can put everything in fminsearch:
[solution, fval] = fminsearch(A, Q0)
```